# Overriding class in Delphi - A Design Pattern Question

Tags: delphi, tframe

I'm currently working with a three-tiered hierarchy of Delphi TFrame objects:

- `TItemsFrame` - A base TFrame defining a scrolling area with items.
- `TDrawItemsFrame` - A TFrame that overrides `TItemsFrame` to define
  how the items are drawn.
- `TFullPage` - Another TFrame that extends `TDrawItemsFrame`, adding header and footer sections.

The twist comes when I have two different projects that each require a unique way to draw the items, without modifying any descendants of `TDrawItemsFrame`.

I imagine the solution would look something like this:

- Main project: `type TItemsFrame = Class(TFrame)`
- Main project: `type TDrawItemsFrame = Class(TItemsFrame)`
- Main project: `type TFullPage = Class({$I AncestorClass.inc})`
- Main project: `type TOtherFullPage = Class({$I AncestorClass.inc})` and so on

Then for the individual projects:

- Project A: Define type `TCustom_A_DrawItemsFrame = Class(TDrawItemsFrame)` and `set AncestorClass.inc to TCustom_A_DrawItemsFrame`.
- Project B: Define `type TCustom_B_DrawItemsFrame = Class(TDrawItemsFrame)` and `set AncestorClass.inc to TCustom_B_DrawItemsFrame`.

My question is, does this approach align with good Delphi practices, or is there a better Strategy Pattern I should consider to solve this problem? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the TFrame instances part of a regular TForm-descendant? AFIK the DFM contains the class names of the Frames, and does not support '{$I AncestorClass.inc}'. Have you tried it?

Comment: in fact the dfm only contain : 
inherited FullPage : TFullPage 
end

so no mention to the name of it's descendant :)

Comment: Without any further knowledge I might miss the point, but I recommend extracting the differences in the drawing code into separate classes and use the appropriate instance.

Comment: I think the proper term is Strategy Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe I updated the question accordinatly :)

Comment: @zeus maybe you can make use of the template method pattern here. But without more details it's hard to give some proper advice

Comment: @DelphiCoder thanks i just read an article about template method patter it's really interesting !

Comment: I think the idea behind Frames is great, but they're a real PITA to use b/c forms with frames on them seem to always fail to load up under what I'd consider "normal" usage conditions. The $I include directive is a compile-time thing, and the IDE isn't going to recognize it. So if there's anything on there that you want to show in the frame, it's not going to show up in the IDE. I think you may be mixing metaphors here. Frames are like specialized forms, but you seem to be trying to use them as visual containers, more like inherited forms. I've never found either one to be easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like Some VCL Components :
on the TItemsFrame class expose an event OnDrawItem with all the parameter that can be modified for every item.

Example :

```
TItemsFrame = class(TFrame)
...
  fExternalDrawEvent : reference to procedure (out OItemColor : TColor);
                       // or procedure (out OItemColor : TColor) of object
  procedure DoExtDraw(out OItemColor : TColor);
...
public
...
  property OnDrawItem : TExternalDrawEvent read : fExternalDrawEvent write fExternalDrawEvent ;
...
end;

TItemsFrame.DoExtDraw(out OItemColor : TColor);
begin
  if assigned(fExternalDrawEvent) then
  begin
    fExternalDrawEvent(OItemColor); 
  end;
end;

procedure TItemsFrame.DrawingItems ;
var 
  lItemColor : TColor;
begin
  ...
  if fExternalDrwaingEnabled then
  begin
    DoExtDraw(lItemColor );
  end;
  ...
  Item[i].color := lItemColor ;
  ...
end;
```

for example the first program :

```
procedure 
var 
  lExampleFrame : TFullPage;
begin
// Create
  lExampleFrame.OnDrawItem(
    procedure (out OItemColor : TColor) 
    begin
      OItemColor := clred; 
    end
  );  

end;
```

for example the second program :

```
procedure 
var 
  lExampleFrame : TFullPage;
begin
// Create
  lExampleFrame.OnDrawItem(
    procedure (out OItemColor : TColor) 
    begin
      OItemColor := clBlue; 
    end
  );  

end;
```